# Pass aurguments to a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React stateless functional component. I would like to pass augments to the callback function.

I have to pass in data.item.id to the invokeFunction

```
const MyComponent = ({ data, invokeFunction }) => (
    <div>
        <a className="pdf-name" onClick={invokeFunction}>{data.item.extension.nameCode}</a>
</div>
)


hydratedata(arg){
console.log("arg", this is the data that is hydrating );
}
```

Comment: `invokeFunction.bind( null, data.item.id )`

Comment: I prefer arrow functions for this: `onClick={() => invokeFunction(data.item.id)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call it through an anonymous function callback, eg:

```
const MyComponent = ({ data, invokeFunction }) => (
    <div>
        <a className="pdf-name" onClick={() => invokeFunction( data.item )}>{data.item.extension.nameCode}</a>
    </div>
);
```

Or as suggested by [@AndyRay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743464/andy-ray), you could also use binding

```
const MyComponent = ({ data, invokeFunction }) => (
    <div>
        <a className="pdf-name" onClick={invokeFunction.bind( null, data.item )}>{data.item.extension.nameCode}</a>
    </div>
);
```

Binding creates a function with preset executioncontext and in this case the first argument, so it only has to call the function

Answer (score 0):

The context of invokeFunction will exist in the component where you passed it in as a prop to MyComponent.

To pass any number of arguments to a callback function, you can create a wrapper function that calls the callback prop with values (that exist in MyComponent's environment/closure) as arguments.

```
const MyComponent = ({ data, invokeFunction }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <a
        className="pdf-name"
        onClick={wrapperFuncForArgs}
      >
        {data.item.extension.nameCode}
      </a>
    </div>
  );

  function wrapperFuncForArgs() {
    invokeFunction(data.item.id);
  }
};
```